# Upgraded Spring boot: Now getting "bad SQL grammar" errors from JDBC and JOOQ

Tags: spring-boot, jooq

So I upgraded Spring Boot starter to 2.3.1 from 2.2.8.

I kept JOOQ at its original 3.11.5 version, as I do not want to go to version 3.12 as it does not support MySQL 5_7 as a free option.

I am now getting *bad SQL grammar* errors from existing queries, I don't even know where to start debugging this as what library upgrade from the starter is causing the issue?

Full error is

```
`Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax\
            ; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version \
            for the right syntax to use near '-1) as `alias_13136459` on \
            `ideas_service`.`challenge`.`id` = `id_alias` left ou' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.execute(ClientPreparedStatement.java:370)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:209)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.executeStatementAndGetFirstResultSet(Tools.java:3483)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:268)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:350)
    ... 122 common frames omitted`
```

Here is the query that gives *bad SQL error*:

```
  public List<ChallengeDetails> findAllChallengesDetails(
      @NonNull Integer offset, @NonNull Integer limit, Integer competitionId) {
    log.info(
        "Find ChallengeEntity(s) (join ChallengeQuestionsEntity) with offset: {}, limit: {}, competitionId: {}",
        offset,
        limit,
        competitionId);

    var challengeIdAlias = CHALLENGE.ID.as("id_alias");

    var filterSelect =
        dsl.select(challengeIdAlias)
            .from(CHALLENGE)
            .where(findAllChallengesCondition(competitionId))
            .orderBy(CHALLENGE.NAME.asc())
            .limit(limit)
            .offset(offset);

    Result<Record> result =
        dsl.select(CHALLENGE.fields())
            .select(CHALLENGE_QUESTIONS.fields())
            .from(CHALLENGE)
            .innerJoin(filterSelect)
            .on(CHALLENGE.ID.eq(challengeIdAlias))
            .leftOuterJoin(CHALLENGE_QUESTIONS)
            .on(CHALLENGE.ID.eq(CHALLENGE_QUESTIONS.CHALLENGE_ID))
            .orderBy(CHALLENGE.ID.asc(), CHALLENGE_QUESTIONS.ID.asc())
            .fetch();

    return intoChallengeDetailsGroups(result)
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(entry -> new ChallengeDetails(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
        .collect(toList());
  }

  private Condition findAllChallengesCondition(Integer competitionId) {
    Condition condition = CHALLENGE.TENANT.eq(getCurrentTenant());
    if (competitionId != null) {
      condition = condition.and(CHALLENGE.COMPETITION_ID.eq(competitionId));
    }
    return condition;
  }
```

Comment: How do you generate the Java Classes in Jooq? Any chance that the generation was made with one jooq version but the runtime actually uses another version? Are you using jooq starter (like here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-support-for-jooq) or configure it by yourself ? What is the dialect? Is jooq.sql-dialect=mysql set somewhere? Does the spring boot configuration code pick it?

Comment: Have you tried using `SQLDialect.MYSQL` in the latest jOOQ version? Apart from a few esoteric hiccups, the dialects are almost the same. Regarding your specific question, can you show your jOOQ query?

Comment: @LukasEder so I actually just upgraded to latest version of Jooq and now use the sql dialect mysql. I still get the bad sql grammer error. I updated the OP

Answer (score 0):

The error can be reproduced in MySQL directly:

```sql
select *
from (select 1 a limit 2, -1) t
```

It produces:

> [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-1) t' at line 2

You shouldn't pass negative numbers to `LIMIT` or `OFFSET`